# assembly segfault when calling printf

Tags: assembly, x86

I used the following code to printf 5 to the screen: it printed:

```
5
segmentation fault(core dumped)
```

Why is this happening?

```
global main
extern printf

section .rodata
format_string db "%d", 0xa,0

main:
mov ecx, 5
push ecx
push format_string
call printf

leave
ret
```

Comment: You have a `leave` but no corresponding `enter` or `push ebp; mov ebp, esp` in the prologue. PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate (the other question has the opposite problem, leaving extra stuff on the stack instead of popping too much), but the answer covers it.